# Email module: Emails are not being sent

Tags: email-contact-form

I have the simplest Email form from EE docs: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html

Upon 'Submit' I get returned to the homepage of our site. Also, there are no Error/Success messages upon form submission.

We are able to send Emails through Tools > Communication.

As a test, we installed Solspaces Freeform (Free version), the same thing happens.

We've used the Email module many times on other sites without any trouble. This time around, we're on a different server and not sure if we're missing something on our config.

EE v2.10.1

> **Update: Resolved**
>
> We had a static index.html on our www folder. Removing that file, fixed the issue.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious suggestion, but what do the logs (both EE and your web server's error logs) say? Try turning on debugging, too.

Comment: There are no logs on EE / and our access to the server is limited. Debugging seems to return everything correctly.

Comment: Are you using PHP Mail? Try using a different method, like SMTP mail. That said, I am not sure you can properly debug this without access to server (particularly error) logs. Perhaps contact host support?

Comment: The culprit: I had index.html (outside of EE build) on our www folder. Meaning: going to www.website.com resolved into this index.html (not through EE installation). Removing that index.html resolved the issue.